# Flux intergrals/Finding normals and their dot products

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

So, I have been stuck on this problem in vector calculus for a while now, and I can't seem to understand the solution given in the text. It is to calculate the flux of the tetrahedon bounded by the coordinate axes and the plane $x-2y+3x=6$ for the function $\mathbf{F} =x\mathbf i + z\mathbf k$. The first thing they do, and the part I'm sort of stuck on, is finding the normals of the different surfaces. For example, the normal to the plane corresponding to $x = 0$, they give as being $\mathbf{\hat{n}} = -\mathbf i$. I get that, since that vector would "point" in the negative direction of the x axis, normal to the plane. However, then they take the dot product and say $\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = 0$.

I'm not entirely sure how they calculated that dot product? As I understand it, it would either be:

$(1)\ \ \ \ \ [x\mathbf i + z\mathbf k] \cdot [-\mathbf j]$, which would be undefined, since they don't have the same number of components, or

$(2)\ \ \ \ \ [x\mathbf i + \mathbf j+ z\mathbf k] \cdot [\mathbf i-\mathbf j+\mathbf k] = (x)+(-1) +(z)$ which isn't equal to zero.

In general, I guess I'm sort of confused about vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ being described as just a single component? Like, is $\mathbf{F} = x\mathbf i$ the same thing as $\mathbf{F} = x\mathbf i + \mathbf j + \mathbf k$? If it isn't, then what would $\mathbf{F}$ represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these vectors have the same number of components -- $3$ -- the question is just leaving off the $0\mathbf i$'s, $0\mathbf j$'s, and $0\mathbf k$'s.  So $\hat {\mathbf n} = -\mathbf i$ is the same thing as $\hat {\mathbf n}=-\mathbf i + 0\mathbf j + 0\mathbf k$.

Comment: Aah, I see! Now it works. Thanks, that really helped me out a lot here.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{F} = x \mathbf{i} = x \mathbf{i} + 0 \cdot \mathbf{j} + 0 \cdot \mathbf{k}$.